# Exclude directory from redirecting to https

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewrite-module

Good day,
I have searched for a solution but all the answers don't work as advertised :-).

The code below works for me to:

1. Redirect all access to HTTPS
2. Allow subdomains to bypass HTTPS

What I need is the directory Payments/Return-Url to also be allowed to bypass HTTPS and allow HTTP access or pass posted values (P instead of L  on the RewriteRule setting breaks the site completely).

```
   RewriteEngine On

   /removing www.
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  /redirecting to https if http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

  # allowing http on sub domain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I have tried the following edits:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(Payments/Return-Url)($|/) - [L]
  .......
```

and also

```
  ..........
  # allowing http on sub domain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Payments/Return-Url [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I am a complete noob with this... I tried to understand the documentation, but it takes me a while to absorb and I need this working asap...

Comment: You do realise how insecure it sound, allowing http on the payment directory ?

Comment: Access is checked against returned variables and referring server.

Comment: Anybody in the network can manipulate http data. Sound like a really bad idea to manipulate insecure data so close of payment processing.